# Android - Video Activity

Tags: java, android

I've set an app that plays videos from internal storage. You can choose videos from the list view but  I would like to add videos to the list view from the URL not internal source. The code looks like this right now:

```
 private void fillVideosList(){
        videosList.clear();
        addVideosFrom(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)));
        addVideosFrom(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));
        addVideosFrom(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)));
```

One more thing.

I have a problem with going back to the previous activity after exiting the video. After I exit video and push the back button it doesn't take me to the previous activity, it takes me to the video once again.

The code for video controller looks like that:

```
 public VideoController(Context context){
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dp = 50f;
        float fpixels = metrics.density * dp;
        int pixels = (int) (fpixels + 0.5f);
        params.bottomMargin = pixels;
        //params.rightMargin = pixels;
        this.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAnchorView(View view){
        super.setAnchorView(view);
        ImageButton exitButton = new ImageButton(context);
        exitButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable((R.drawable.exit)));
        exitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        addView(exitButton, params);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayer.class);
                intent.putExtra((VIDEO_ACTIVITY_INTENT), "showContinueWatching");
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is MediaController consumed KEYCODE_BACK event in below codes, if you want KEYCODE_BACK event send to Activity normally, all you have to do is override the dispatchKeyEvent method of MediaController, deal with like this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return false; 
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```